# Why can't pyautogui find the picture?

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
    
button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('picturee.png')
print("finished")
```

The picture works perfect in a HTML file i created.

[image: Th Error]
[image: My files]

Comment: Is that _actually_ a png file?

Comment: yeah i double checked it and it worked in the HTML file as a png.

Comment: Please show the output of running `dir` while in that directory so we have hard evidence that that's the case. Also please put `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` in your script and tell us if the output is the folder your script and image are in.

Comment: Have you tried changing the working directory to where the script and png are? `pyautogui` requires the images be in the same directory you're launching your script from.

Comment: You only specified a filename, so the file is being looked for in the current working directory - which is `C:\Users\x`, not the location where your script is.

Comment: It says filenotfounderror...give the correct path to picturee.png file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into the source code, we are directed from [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) to [pyscreeze](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze) where we can see the following block of code in the location functions.

```py
    if isinstance(needleImage, (str, unicode)):
        # 'image' is a filename, load the Image object
        needleFileObj = open(needleImage, 'rb')
        needleImage = Image.open(needleFileObj)
```

In short, you need the image to be in the same directory as the one you're launching the script from.

[Link to source](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/28ab707dceecbdd135a9491c3f8effd3a69680af/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L260-L263)